# Changing string value in OnClick

Tags: android

Fairly new to android programming and having trouble changing the string value "channel" when a button is clicked. Having issues trying to close the onCreate but it only seems to let me close it at the end of the activity. I get an error of 'token "}". please delete' if i try to close it elsewhere. I'm having a hard time trying to wrap my head around this even though it's probably very simple.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity { 

    String channel = "bbc1";

    // This method creates main application view
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        // Set view
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final ViewSwitcher switcher = (ViewSwitcher)findViewById(R.id.ViewSwitcher1);
        Button bbcButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bbcButton);
        Button bbc2Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bbc2Button);



        bbcButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                channel = "bbc1";
                switcher.showNext();    
            }   
        });


        bbc2Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                channel = "bbc2";
                switcher.showNext();
            }
        });


        try{
            // This line creates RSS reader
            RssReader rssReader = new RssReader("http://bleb.org/tv/data/rss.php?ch="+channel+"&day=0");

            // This line gets a ListView from main view
            ListView tvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMainView);

            // This line creates a list adapter
            ArrayAdapter<RssItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, rssReader.getItems());

            // This line sets list adapter for the ListView
            tvItems.setAdapter(adapter);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Tv RSS Reader", e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: From the code you posted, everything seems fine.  The two closing `}` at the end are one for the `onCreate` method and the other - for the class. I formatted your code so that you can see it better.

Comment: try to copy full code, remove code and paste code. CTRL+A,CTRL+C,CTRL+A,DELETE,CTRL+V.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want to change the RSS feed when you press the button. But since you are fetching the RSS info in the onCreate, you won't update the data, even though you are pressing the buttons. But you are changing the value of the string channel.

onCreate is only called once when you create the activity!

Try moving the try-statement into a seperate method and call this method in your two onClickListeners.

```
    bbc2Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            channel = "bbc2";
            updateRSS();
            switcher.showNext();
        }
    });

    public void updateRSS(){
        try{
           // This line creates RSS reader
           RssReader rssReader = new RssReader("http://bleb.org/tv/data/rss.php?ch="+channel+"&day=0");

           // This line gets a ListView from main view
           ListView tvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMainView);

           // This line creates a list adapter
           ArrayAdapter<RssItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, rssReader.getItems());

           // This line sets list adapter for the ListView
           tvItems.setAdapter(adapter);


        } catch (Exception e) {
           Log.e("Tv RSS Reader", e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! That was such a massive help. Makes total sense now, stupid mistake, staring at code for too long I think haha